# How to use overflow:hidden only on the last dt of an dl

Tags: css, overflow

I'm not sure, if there's a(n easy) solution, but the problem looks like this:

I've got an pretty basic Accordion built with a dl;

```
<dl>
<dt>MenueLink1</dt>
<dd>Content1</dd>
<dt>MenueLink2</dt>
<dd>Content2</dd>
.
.
.
<dt>Logo</dt>
</dl>
```

The last dt contains a logo. And here's the scoop: I want to use overflow:hidden only for the last dt containing the logo. So if the Logo moves outside the browser/screen (as a result of the different heights of the Content-DDs) I don't want the Browser to show a scrollbar, but as soon as another dd or dt leaves the screen/browser the scrollbar should appear. 
My first Idea was to put the logo in a seperate div outside the dl, but then it doesn't move up and down with the rest of the dl when the height changes...

I would be really happy if anyone can give me a hint or a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what browsers you need to support. The selector `dl dt:last-child` will work for you [if the browsers you target support it](http://kimblim.dk/css-tests/selectors/).

Otherwise, the usual practice is to give the class `last-item` to the last `dt` when you are generating the HTML and use `dl dt.last-item` which is of course universally supported.

Comment: May be logo is in a "dd"( if it is not static page ). So selector must be dl *:last-child. I'm not right?

Comment: @moses: If it can be a `dd` then you 're right. Alternatively, `dl dt:last-of-type` will work but it's not supported by FF 3.0 in addition to IE 6-8 (which don't support `:last-child` already).

Comment: Yes, it' not supported. JavaScript must be used.

Comment: Hm doesn't work or I don't get what you are talking about. The last "dt" has the ability overflow:hidden (via an id) and a margin [and nothing else] and contains a "span" with a height and width and the logo as an background-image. Still the Scrollbar appears as soon, as the logo leaves the screen...